# Empty 'The bibiography' environment and citation undefined. Help!

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\title{\textit{The Role of The Developmental Transcription Factor Brachyury in the development of Colorectal Cancer}}
\author{Jason Saunders Williams}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics{Logo.png}
\end{figure}
\maketitle
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
Cancer \cite{Aramaki2013}
\chapter{Materials and Methods}
\chapter{Results}
\chapter{Discussion}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{BibTex.bib}
\end{document}
```

The error message that I get is:

```
line 44 Citation `Aramaki2013' on page 4 undefined
line 3 Empty `thebibliography' environment
line 1 There were undefined citations.
```

The BibTeX file is in the same folder as the latex file. Really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! `\bibliography{<filename without extension>}` i.e. drop the `.bib`. You need to run `bibtex` after compiling and then compile at least twice more.

Comment: If you need more help, you'll need to show us the relevant entry from the `.bib` file and remove the graphics stuff from your example code since we don't have `Logo.png`.

Comment: see if this helps: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: Hi cfr. Thanks, I tried deleting the file extension and I still get the same message. Do you mean I need to run the bibtex package as well as natbib?

Comment: Hi guys, I've manged to get it working now. I'm using texmaker with Mendeley. Just in case anyone has the same problem I'll run through how I managed to get it to work: Follow the instructions from here to configure the correct settings in Mendeley ensuring that you put your BibTex file in the same folder as your .tex file. Then, in texmaker, you do not need to tell it which package to use in the preamble, it's already there under the Tools menu as BibTex or F11. Click on this or press F11. That's all you need to do then is define your bibliography style and tell LaTex where the file is.

Comment: (http://barrington.cranfield.ac.uk/help/BibTeXMendeley.pdf) to...configure the correct settings in Mendeley ensuring that you put your BibTex file in the same folder as your .tex file. Then, in texmaker, you do not need to tell it which package to use in the preamble, it's already there under the Tools menu as BibTex or F11. Click on this or press F11. That's all you need to do then is define your bibliography style and tell LaTex where the file is i.e. \bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{bibtex} before the end of the document.